# Linker error in function

Tags: c++, function, linker, arguments, linker-errors

first post here as I'm stuck with my wonderful C++ function.

The error I'm getting is a linker error and as follows:

> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void **thiscall controls::printText(int,int,int,int,int,char const *,struct HWND** *)" (?printText@controls@@QAEXHHHHHPBDPAUHWND__@@@Z) referenced in function "long **stdcall WndProc(struct HWND** *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WndProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
>
> C:\Users\HIDDEN\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TimedShutdown\Debug\TimedShutdown.exe : fatal >error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Basically I'm trying to have a class for creating win32 controls and painting text and the function to paint text is where my problem occurs.

Code is as follows:

> The controls.h file segment:-

```
void printText( int R, int G, int B, int x, int y, LPCSTR text, HWND parent);
```

> The controls.cpp segment

```
void printText(int R, int G, int B, int x, int y, LPCSTR text, HWND parent)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT pss;
    hdc = BeginPaint(parent, &pss);
    SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
    SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(R,G,B));
    TextOut(hdc, 30, 20, text, strlen(text));       
    EndPaint(parent, &pss);
}
```

> The main.cpp call

```
controls ctrls;
ctrls->printText(255,0,0,300,50,"Test text",hWnd);
```

I've removed the call and the error still occurs. Initially I was attempting to pass the HDC and PAINTSTRUCT to the function also but I've removed that whilst trying to identify the error source.

Im totally lost guys, im not an amazing C++ programmer but I am in the process of learning.

critisise me, I demand it!

Thanks in advance for any help given, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to tell the compiler that the function `printText` in `controls.cpp` is `controls::printText`. So, it is still undefined for the compiler.

Modifications you have to do in `controls.cpp`:

```
// This part is really important
// It tells the compiler which function is defined
//       |
//   vvvvvvvvvv
void controls::printText(int R, int G, int B, int x, int y, LPCSTR text, HWND parent)
{ // ...
```

**Note**: The color passed to printText is probably R8G8B8, ie 8 bits per component. If I'm right, you should use `unsigned char` instead of `int` for `R`, `G` and `B`.

Comment: Such a simple mistake i was overlooking =\  thank you very much :D

Comment: You're welcome ;) Please do not forget to accept an anwser, by clicking on the green tick at the bottom of the vote counter.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified `controls::` to the function name where you define it. If you do not do this you can't expect it to behave like a member function of controls class.
Try this instead of your current declaration

```
void controls::printText(int R, int G, int B, int x, int y, LPCSTR text, HWND parent)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT pss;
    hdc = BeginPaint(parent, &pss);
    SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
    SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(R,G,B));
    TextOut(hdc, 30, 20, text, strlen(text));       
    EndPaint(parent, &pss);
}
```

**Edit:** It is not clear from the code you provided in your question that you have actually got printText as a member function of controls, but the way in which you call it from your code suggests that is how you intend it to function.